# How to start jQuery animation on window load with animate function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I was making this animation where all the divs get scaled double and rotated 0 deg from its initial state on window load and keeps animating after 8 secs. but this does not work. I used jQuery animate to make that happen but it seems I did something wrong for which it is not working. please help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gallery Arijit</title>

<style type="text/css">
    .nvidia{
        width: 230px;
        height: 230px;
        border:1px solid black; 
        position: relative;
        left:130px;
        top: 150px;
        float: left;
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px 1px #333333;
        transition: all 0.5s linear;
    }
    .nvidia:nth-child(even){
        transform:rotate(15deg);
    }
    .nvidia:nth-child(odd){
        transform:rotate(-15deg);
    }
    /*.nvidia:nth-child(even):hover{
        transform:rotate(0deg) scale(2,2);
        z-index:1000;
    }
    .nvidia:nth-child(odd):hover{
        transform:rotate(0deg) scale(2,2);
        z-index:1000;   
    }*/
    img{
        margin:10px 10px 4px 23px; 
    }

    p{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 8px;
        padding: 3px;

    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="nvidia div1">
    <img src="nvidia-logo.jpg" width="180" height="180">
    <p>This is Nvidia logo.An awesome GPU Company.I ove it</p>
</div>
<div class="nvidia div2">
    <img src="nvidia-logo.jpg" width="180" height="180">
    <p>This is Nvidia logo.An awesome GPU Company.I ove it</p>
</div>
<div class="nvidia div3">
    <img src="nvidia-logo.jpg" width="180" height="180">
    <p>This is Nvidia logo.An awesome GPU Company.I ove it</p>
</div>
<div class="nvidia div4">
    <img src="nvidia-logo.jpg" width="180" height="180">
    <p>This is Nvidia logo.An awesome GPU Company.I ove it</p>
</div>
<div class="nvidia div5">
    <img src="nvidia-logo.jpg" width="180" height="180">
    <p>This is Nvidia logo.An awesome GPU Company.I ove it</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(ani,8000);
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ani(){
        $(".div1").animate({transform:'rotate(0deg) scale(2,2)',z-index:'1000'},"slow");
        $(".div2").animate({transform:'rotate(0deg) scale(2,2)',z-index:'1000'},"slow");
        $(".div3").animate({transform:'rotate(0deg) scale(2,2)',z-index:'1000'},"slow");
        $(".div4").animate({transform:'rotate(0deg) scale(2,2)',z-index:'1000'},"slow");
        $(".div5").animate({transform:'rotate(0deg) scale(2,2)',z-index:'1000'},"slow");
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple problems in your code. The z-index key key is causing syntax problems. Once you have that fixed, transform doesn't seem to work with jQuery animate. Try using css instead.

```
function ani(){
    $(".div1").css({transform:'rotate(0deg) scale(2,2)'},"slow");
    $(".div2").css({transform:'rotate(0deg) scale(2,2)'},"slow");
    $(".div3").css({transform:'rotate(0deg) scale(2,2)'},"slow");
    $(".div4").css({transform:'rotate(0deg) scale(2,2)'},"slow");
    $(".div5").css({transform:'rotate(0deg) scale(2,2)'},"slow");
}
```

Here is a fiddle of the changes I listed above
http://jsfiddle.net/v1c72ueL/

Comment: Thanks for the info.but I want those to animate one by one. if I use css then they will start animating all together where as in animate function we can do the animate in queue. so how to fix that sir?

Comment: Even in your code, had animate worked I think it would have animated them all at once. Your setInterval function can be used to animate them one by one

http://jsfiddle.net/v1c72ueL/1/

Comment: what is not the function looping?

Answer (score 0):

try this one with z-index

```
 $(".div1").css({transform:'rotate(0deg) scale(2,2)','z-index':'1000'},"slow");
$(".div2").css({transform:'rotate(0deg) scale(2,2)','z-index':'1000'},"slow");
$(".div3").css({transform:'rotate(0deg) scale(2,2)','z-index':'1000'},"slow");
$(".div4").css({transform:'rotate(0deg) scale(2,2)','z-index':'1000'},"slow");
$(".div5").css({transform:'rotate(0deg) scale(2,2)','z-index':'1000'},"slow");
```